# how to receive always the same dateformat to insert into sql table from regional set dateformat datepicker (ui jquery)

Tags: mysql, jquery-ui

I want to use ui datepicker jquery.
I set the datepicker up like this:

```
        $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );
    $( "#BeginnDate" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "us" ] );
```

but i have to write the date after sending the form as dd-mm-yyyy in to the sql table.

depending on the country, the received dateformat can be different.
but i always need at the end dd-mm-yyyy.

is there a option or a trick that i can convert the date into a hidden field with a datepicker function to this format, so i make sure i will receive always the same format?

#### Update:

I found out the following:

If I do this, the field `alternateDate` does not get a value but the format for the date is right after sending the form

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[""] );
$( "#BeginnDate" ).datepicker(      $.datepicker.regional[ "us" ]  );   
$( "#BeginnDate" ).datepicker({     altField: "#alternateDate", altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"  });
```

If I do that, the field alternateDate gets a value but the formatdate does not work

```
$( "#BeginnDate" ).datepicker({     altField: "#alternateDate", altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"  });
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[""] );
$( "#BeginnDate" ).datepicker(      $.datepicker.regional[ "us" ]  );
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [alt-field](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#alt-field) to make the datepicker put a different formatted date in another (hidden) field.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. that was precise what i needed. thank you so much, you saved my day. beside, this is my favorit forum. i already found many anwsers for a lot of questions here. a very good and helpfull community. best regards Ludwig